# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'else' when running SQL command

Tags: sql

I am getting the following area message when executing this SQL query:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'else'

Here is the query:

```
SELECT
    *,
    CASE 
        WHEN los IN (0, 1, 2, 3, 4) THEN 'under 5'
        WHEN los >= 5 THEN 'above 5'
        ELSE 'Unknown' 
    END AS los_type
FROM
    (SELECT 
         CASE
            WHEN LEN(comp.AGTNUMBER) = 6 THEN substring(comp.AGTNUMBER, 2, 5) 
            ELSE comp.AGTNUMBER 
         END AS FR_Number,
         comp.COMPLAINTNUMBER,
         YEAR(comp.opendate) AS Comp_Year,
         comp.COMPLAINTORIGIN,
         comp.COMPTYPE AS Comp_Type,
         comp.OPENDATE,
         comp.REBUTTAL,
         comp.AGENTNAMEINCOM,
         CASE
            WHEN fr.FULL_TIME_SVC_DTE < comp.OPENDATE 
               THEN FLOOR(DATEDIFF(MONTH, fr.FULL_TIME_SVC_DTE, comp.OPENDATE) / 12)
            WHEN fr.FULL_TIME_SVC_DTE > comp.OPENDATE 
               THEN floor(datediff(month, fr.ACTUAL_CONTRACT_END_DATE, fr.FULL_TIME_SVC_DTE) / 12
            ELSE NULL 
        END AS los
     FROM 
         dbo.EC_Complaints_Info AS comp
     LEFT JOIN
         dbo.FLD_REP_Info AS fr 
             ON CASE WHEN LEN(comp.AGTNUMBER) = 6 
                       THEN substring(comp.AGTNUMBER, 2, 5) 
                    ELSE comp.AGTNUMBER 
               END = fr.FR_NUMBER
             AND comp.OPENDATE BETWEEN fr.ACTUAL_CONTRACT_START_DATE 
                                   AND fr.ACTUAL_CONTRACT_END_DATE
     WHERE
        ((comp.REBUTTAL = 'No'))
        AND ((comp.STATUS = 'open') OR
             (comp.STATUS = 'closed'))
 ) AS a
```

Can anyone help me figure out why I'm getting this error message?

Comment: Which else is the error for?

Comment: Where is your error text?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a `)` in one of your `CASE` expressions:

```
case when fr.FULL_TIME_SVC_DTE < comp.OPENDATE then floor(datediff(month, fr.FULL_TIME_SVC_DTE, comp.OPENDATE)/12)
       when fr.FULL_TIME_SVC_DTE > comp.OPENDATE 
       then floor(datediff(month, fr.ACTUAL_CONTRACT_END_DATE, fr.FULL_TIME_SVC_DTE)/12 --here is the error
                         else null end as los
```

It should be:

```
case when fr.FULL_TIME_SVC_DTE < comp.OPENDATE then floor(datediff(month, fr.FULL_TIME_SVC_DTE, comp.OPENDATE)/12)
       when fr.FULL_TIME_SVC_DTE > comp.OPENDATE 
       then floor(datediff(month, fr.ACTUAL_CONTRACT_END_DATE, fr.FULL_TIME_SVC_DTE)/12)
                         else null end as los
```